# Retrieving 2 arrays from a txt file with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the easiest way to retrieve 2 arrays from 1 txt file with javascript?

so

```
Steve~kid
Bob~adult
Chris~kid
```

becomes

Names array

```
Steve, Bob, Chris
```

& 
Type array

```
kid, adult, kid
```

Comment: You might also consider one array of objects: `[{"name":"Steve","type":"kid"}, ...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you can't access system files from the browser, although there are some options such as the [fileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) in some modern browsers and of course, [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/), but that's for server stuff.

**Note:** If the files are *on* ***your*** server then you can do an AJAX request.

But assuming you find out how to get the contents of the file into a string variable, you can create the arrays like:

```
var str = 'Steve~kid\nBob~adult\nChris~kid', // string from file
    lines = str.split('\n'),
    names = [],
    types = [];

lines.forEach(function( v ) {
  var a = v.split('~');
  names.push( a[0] );
  types.push( a[1] );
});

console.log( names ); //=> ['Steve', 'Bob', 'Chris']
console.log( types ); //=> ['kid', 'adult', 'kid']
```

Comment: The names work, but this returns 
kid
,adult
,kid on seperate lines for types

Comment: I was able to resolve this by adding ~ to the end of every line

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$.get('/something.txt', function(data){
        var first=data.split('\n');
        var second = new Array();
        for(i=0;i<first.length;i++)
        {
          second[i] = first[i].substring(first[i].indexOf("~")+1);
        }
        //Do something with arrays
});
```